# Wireless internet works on W7 and on University Network but is extremely slow at home

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with an Atheros wireless card. My internet speed in W7 is great. My internet speed in Ubuntu 12.04 at a university network is great.
My internet speed in Ubuntu 12.04 at my home network is really slow.

Some solutions I have tried but didn't work:

- Disabling IPv6
- Running the following code:

  ```
  sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
  sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi
  sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
  sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
  ```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -s
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Found this code on here somewhere. 
It fixed my problem. Might not work immediately though. I had to do a restart.